# Replace/alter/rename form labels in theme

Tags: theming, emails

I installed this [Simplenews](https://drupal.org/project/simplenews) module, and it gives default field to enter your email to subscribe for newsletter and the fields title is just `'Email:'` and I need to change it to something else.

It looks like it's hardcoded and I could just dig through modules files and edit, but I know this is not recommended.

I was hoping maybe I could just paste in some preprocess function to theme's template.php file and replace 'Email:' with e.g. 'Join Our Mailing List:'.

Path to label is `form.simplenews-subscribe div div label`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Put this code to your theme's template.php, where's THEME replace it with your theme's dir name. So then where's `#title = t()` you put in your own custom title for the field. So what it does it alters given forms field, in this case it's `simplenews_block_form` inlcuded in between `THEME_form_simplenews_block_form_alter`

```
function THEME_form_simplenews_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['mail']['#title'] = t('Join Our Mailing List:');
}
```

Clear cache!

Comment: I added some explanations.